# Can't change value of element called from state React

Tags: reactjs

I have several elements that must be displayed from Function. 
because it can't directly call an element from Function, I put it in state.

Everything works fine but I can't change the value

this is an example

```
class FormLowongan extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            cobaElement: "",
            cobaValue: "first value"
        }

        this.cobaRender = this.cobaRender.bind(this);
        this.cobaChange = this.cobaChange.bind(this);
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        this.cobaRender();
    }

    cobaRender() {
        let coba = <input type="text" name="coba" class="form-control" value={this.state.cobaValue} onChange={this.cobaChange.bind(this)} />;

        this.setState({
            cobaElement: coba
        })
    }

    cobaChange(e) {
        this.setState({
            cobaValue: e.target.value
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div class="content">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-3">Coba</label>
                    <div class="col-md-9">
                        {this.state.cobaElement}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change your onChange method with this
 *onChange={e => this.cobaChange(e)}*